Flutter project automatically closed when running in Android device or Emulator
good day!
I am currently working on a Flutter project using Java 17, Flutter 3.7.12, and Android Studio. The project runs successfully on Chrome (web) and on a Medium phone emulator (API 35). However, when I try to run it on an Android x64-bit device, I encounter the following error:
E/FlutterLoader(10414): Flutter initialization failed. E/FlutterLoader(10414): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so" E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:164) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterLoader.java:239) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.<init>(FlutterEngine.java:327) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.<init>(FlutterEngine.java:207) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.setupFlutterEngine(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:272) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:181) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:495) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6760) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779) E/FlutterLoader(10414): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so" E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:985) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1562) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary(FlutterJNI.java:141) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:189) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:182) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) E/FlutterLoader(10414):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) E/AndroidRuntime(10414): FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(10414): Process: com.atinity.public_emergency_app, PID: 10414 E/AndroidRuntime(10414): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.atinity.public_emergency_app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so" E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779) E/AndroidRuntime(10414): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so" E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterLoader.java:345) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.<init>(FlutterEngine.java:327) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.<init>(FlutterEngine.java:207) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.setupFlutterEngine(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:272) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:181) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:495) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6760) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    ... 9 more E/AndroidRuntime(10414): Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so" E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:164) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterLoader.java:239) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    ... 17 more E/AndroidRuntime(10414): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.atinity.public_emergency_app-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so" E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:985) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1562) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary(FlutterJNI.java:141) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:189) E/AndroidRuntime(10414):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:182) 
android/app/build.gradle
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
 (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.atinity.public_emergency_app"
 
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}


//pubspec.yaml
name: public_emergency_app
description: Flutter Application to assist individuals in emergency situations by providing real-time communication with first responders and medical professionals
publish_to: 'none'  

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.4 <3.0.0'

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.8.0
  firebase_database: ^10.0.16
  get: ^4.6.5
  firebase_auth: ^4.3.0
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.1
  google_fonts: ^4.0.3
  curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.3
  url_launcher: ^6.1.10
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  android_intent_plus: ^3.1.6
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  geocoding: ^2.1.0
  flutter_sms: ^2.3.3
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.20
  zego_uikit_prebuilt_live_streaming: ^2.3.6
  background_sms: ^0.0.4
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.5
  sliding_switch: ^1.1.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/logos/emergencyAppLogo.png
    - assets/logos/policeman.png
    - assets/logos/ambulance.png
    - assets/logos/fire-brigade.png
    - assets/Ambulance.png
    - assets/Quick.png
    - assets/Choose.png
    - assets/logos/hospital.png
    - assets/logos/fire-truck.png



android/build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


Could you please assist me in resolving this issue? I appreciate your time and support.
Thank you very much!
